# How to replace partial strings within a df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table. Some entries within the StockCode column have letters at the end, how do I replace these with a number?

I could make a dictionary to map each letter to a number but I feel there a quicker way to do so.

```
InvoiceNo  |StockCode |
0   536     85123   
1   536     71053Z  
2   536     84406B  
3   536     22623S
```

Comment: with what number exactly? or can should it be with random number?

Comment: A dictionary to map the replacements is a good idea. Then write a little function to do the replacement and use apply() to map the function to each value in the column. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: @Ch3steR One number corresponding to each letter

Comment: I understood that but with what number do what to replace? Let's say to want to replace `z`, with what number you want to replace `z`? `1`?..2?...3??...4??? or you want to replace with any number randomly?

Comment: @Ch3steR Ah my bad, random as fine as long as it's consistent. so z should always be replaced with the same value.

Comment: Can there be multiple alphabets at the end? like `1235AZV`??

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes up to 3 strings but only ever at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
# Make some data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'InvoiceNo':536,
    'StockCode':['85123', '71053Z', '84406B', '22623S']
})

# Define replacements in a dictionary. (Note the values are strings, not ints)
replacements = {'Z':'1', 'B':'2', 'S':'3'}

#-- Edit per OP's comment ---------------
import string
keys = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
values = [str(i) for i in range(len(keys))]
replacements = dict(zip(keys, values))
#---------------------------------------

# Rebuild Stockcode
# 1) df.StockCode.str.extract('^(\d+)') extracts every sequence of numbers in StockCode, up until the first non-number character
# 2) df.StockCode.str.extract('([A-Z])$') extracts the non-number character at the end of each string
# 3) .replace(replacements).fillna('') makes the replacements and then changes NaN to ''
# 4) adding two series of strings concatenates them
df['StockCode'] = (df.StockCode.str.extract('^(\d+)') + 
                   df.StockCode.str.extract('([A-Z])$').replace(replacements).fillna(''))

print(df)
   InvoiceNo StockCode
0        536     85123
1        536    710531
2        536    844062
3        536    226233
```

The key to this is about understanding [regular expressions](https://regexone.com/).

Comment: Thanks Ben, is there any way to generate that replacement dictionary on the fly or do I have to manually assign the entire alphabet to a number?

Comment: I thought you wanted a more dynamic replacement mechanism. In that case, just use `df['StockCode'] = df.StockCode.str.replace('([A-Z])$', '999')` or whatever number you want to use.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I do want a dynamic replacement, however, I would like to create this replacement dictionary dynamically. Is there a method that doesn't require making a dictionary containing all the letters i.e replacements = {'A':'1', 'B':'2', 'C':'3'...Z:26}? This would be ideal for managing large df with various combinations of substrings at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) which is similar to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), you can pass a function to `repl` param.

```
from random import randint
from string import ascii_uppercase

mapping = {char:str(randint(0, 9)) for char in ascii_uppercase} 
#{'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '1', 'D': '1', 'E': '4', 'F': '9', 'G': '9', 'H': '5',
#'I': '8', 'J': '0', 'K': '0', 'L': '1', 'M': '5', 'N': '3', 'O': '8', 'P': '5', 
#'Q': '5', 'R': '8', 'S': '9', 'T': '8', 'U': '0', 'V': '8', 'W': '1', 'X': '6', 
#'Y': '7', 'Z': '5'}

def repl(match):
    return ''.join(mapping[char] for char in match.group(0))

df['StockCode'] = df['StockCode'].str.replace(r"[A-Z]{,3}$", repl)
df

  InvoiceNo StockCode
0        536     85123
1        536    710535  # 'Z' -> 5
2        536    844063  # 'B' -> 3
3        536    226239  # 'S' -> 9
```

When there is more than one alphabet at the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'InvoiceNo':536,
     'StockCode':['85123', '71053ZAZ', '84406BAR', '22623BIR']
    })
df['StockCode'] = df['StockCode'].str.replace(r"[A-Z]{,3}$", repl)

   InvoiceNo  StockCode
0        536      85123
1        536   71053515  # 'ZAZ' -> '515'
2        536   84406318  # 'BAR' -> '318'
3        536   22623388  # 'BIR' -> '388'
```

- Details about regex pattern used [`r"[A-Z]{,3}$"` in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3Bd5qd/1)

Comment: This method seems to produce repeat characters seen in mappings, check A and C for example. But I've fixed by using Bens edit and combined with your repl. Thanks for your help, got a robust solution and learnt something along the way.